# Retrieve parent-child hierarchy from a self-referencing mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a mysql table structured like this (removed other columns, not relevant to the question):

```
id          parent_id
----------- -----------
1           0          
2           0            
3           0          
4           3          
5           2
6           1
7           1
```

A "parent" is a row that has `parent_id = 0`.

I would like to know if there is a  way to formulate the query so that MySQL outputs the rows with each children right after its parents?

The intended result would be

```
id          parent_id
----------- -----------
1           0          
6           1            
7           1          
2           0          
5           2          
3           0          
4           3
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL does not support recursive queries, so if a child can have childs there's no way to formulate such a query. Otherwise this query should return the rows in the order that you need:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN parent_id=0 THEN id ELSE parent_id END,
  id
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d418bb/1). The trick is to order rows by `id` if it's a parent or by `parent_id` if it's a child, and then by `id`.

Comment: Genius. Never saw the use of CASE before. Powerful!!